# Bitmap cropping: some misunderstandings and some help would be welcome

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey

I'm working on a small project integrating bitmap croping but the result expected is not here.
The sample firemonkey project has a TImage with a picture loaded. I'm drawing a rectange to select what kind of the bitmap part should be "extracted". Here is the obtained result :

[image]

So, when I click on the "Crop" button here is what the result is :

[image]

As you could see, on the top and bottom, I've lost some bitpmap lines.

Here is the code behind the OnClick event :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lBmp: TBitmap;
  xScale, yScale: extended;
  iRect: TRect;
begin
  if Rectangle1.Visible then
  begin
    lBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      xScale := Image1.Bitmap.Width / Image1.Width;
      yScale := Image1.Bitmap.Height / Image1.Height;

      lBmp.Width := round(Rectangle1.Width * xScale);
      lBmp.Height := round(Rectangle1.Height * yScale);

      iRect.Left := round(Rectangle1.Position.X * xScale);
      iRect.Top := round(Rectangle1.Position.Y * yScale);
      iRect.Width := round(Rectangle1.Width * xScale);
      iRect.Height := round(Rectangle1.Height * yScale);

      lBmp.CopyFromBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, iRect, 0, 0);

      Image1.Bitmap.Clear(0);
      Image1.Bitmap := lBmp;

      Rectangle1.Visible := False;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(lBmp);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Rectangle1.Visible := True;
    Rectangle1.Width := Round(Panel1.Width * 0.5);
    Rectangle1.Height := Round(Rectangle1.Width * 1.41);
    Rectangle1.Position.X := Round(Panel1.Width * 0.5)-(Rectangle1.Width * 0.5);
    Rectangle1.Position.Y := Round(Panel1.Height * 0.5)-(Rectangle1.Height * 0.5);
  end;
end;
```

If someone could help me on what's wrong with my code, it could be very nice.

@Tom Brunberg here is the link where you could download the sample project

[CropPicture.rar](https://mega.nz/file/BIsWxaYD#aoWRNeZbwFV9-I9W8tmq_6TlB6A8RHTlr4uxNofb3_8)

Thank you

Comment: Please add the content of the `.fmx` file. I believe I know how to correct your issue, but I want to make a test myself before I post my thoughts.

Comment: @TomBrunberg : Thank you for your feedback. You'll find at the end of my first post, the complete project compressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale calculation is needed, but I'm not sure why you calculate different scales for horizontal and vertical, so I removed that difference by simply assigning the higher scale to the other:

```
  if xScale > yScale
  then yscale := xScale
  else xscale := yScale;
```

You may want to replace that with a single variable.

This corrects the "missing pixel rows" partly

The other problem is related to different sizes of original picture and the "cut out part". To correct the difference in selected area (red line rectangle) and replicated area, I added `offsetX` and `OffsetY` variables that are calculated:

```
var
  OffsetX, OffsetY: extended;
---

  // added offset terms to compensate for the space between
  // picture and Image1 border
  offsetx := (Image1.Width - Image1.Bitmap.Width / xscale) / 2;
  offsety := (Image1.Height - Image1.Bitmap.Height / yscale) / 2;

  // offset terms added here
  iRect.Left   := round((Rectangle1.Position.X - offsetx) * xscale);
  iRect.Top    := round((Rectangle1.Position.Y - offsety) * yscale);
  iRect.Width  := round(Rectangle1.Width * xscale);
  iRect.Height := round(Rectangle1.Height * yscale);
```

This is necessary when the images `WrapMode` is `Fit` which maintains the images aspect ratio.

It is more easy to test this on a PC, so I modified the test application with two images beside each other and the result is here:

[image]

The selection indicator is 1 pixel red line and the rectangle has a fill of 30% light gray. The right side picture matches the selected area on the left picture even though the left picture is limited by top and bottom sides, and the right is limited by the left and right sides.

I renamed the procedure because I call it from different places (like when resizing the form and when dragging the selection rectangle with the mouse, needs some tuning still ;) )

```
procedure TForm2.UpdateDisplay;
var
  lBmp: TBitmap;
  xScale, yScale, scale: extended;
  iRect: TRect;
  OffsetX, OffsetY: extended;
  BmpHwRatio: extended;
  DispRatio: extended;
begin
  if Rectangle1.Visible then
  begin
    lBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      xScale := Image1.Bitmap.Width / Image1.Width;
      yScale := Image1.Bitmap.Height / Image1.Height;

      if xScale > yScale
      then yscale := xScale
      else xscale := yScale;

      lBmp.Width := round(Rectangle1.Width * xScale);
      lBmp.Height := round(Rectangle1.Height * yScale);

      // added offset terms to compensate for the space between
      // picture and Image1 border
      offsetx := (Image1.Width - Image1.Bitmap.Width / xscale) / 2;
      offsety := (Image1.Height - Image1.Bitmap.Height / yscale) / 2;
// You can test without the offset calculations
//      offsetx := 0;
//      offsety := 0;

      // offset terms added here
      iRect.Left   := round((Rectangle1.Position.X - offsetx) * xscale);
      iRect.Top    := round((Rectangle1.Position.Y - offsety) * yscale);
      iRect.Width  := round(Rectangle1.Width * xscale);
      iRect.Height := round(Rectangle1.Height * yscale);

      if iRect.Left < 0 then iRect.Left := 0;
      if iRect.Top  < 0 then iRect.Top  := 0;
      if iRect.Width < 1 then iRect.Width := 1;
      if iRect.Height > (LBMp.Height-1) then iRect.Height := LBmp.Height;

      lBmp.CopyFromBitmap(Image1.Bitmap, iRect, 0, 0);

      Image2.Bitmap.Clear(0);
      Image2.Bitmap := lBmp;

//      Rectangle1.Visible := False;  outcommented to be able to compare images
    finally
      FreeAndNil(lBmp);
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    Rectangle1.Visible := True;
    Rectangle1.Width := Round(Panel1.Width * 0.5);
    Rectangle1.Height := Round(Rectangle1.Width * 1.41);
    Rectangle1.Position.X := Round(Panel1.Width * 0.5)-(Rectangle1.Width * 0.5);
    Rectangle1.Position.Y := Round(Panel1.Height * 0.5)-(Rectangle1.Height * 0.5);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for your precious help. From my side, I had try using Offset too then, your code had really help me. Now, my croping works like a charm.  PS: How do you implement the fade effect inside your rectangle ?

Comment: @Laurent For the fade effect I use the `Opacity` property. Btw, if my post answers your question you can click the tick mark beside it, green.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of [TImage.Bitmap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Objects.TImage.Bitmap) property the returned Bitmap might already be scaled.

> The Bitmap getter uses the following algorithm to retrieve the Bitmap
> property's value:
>
> 1. Using the GetSceneScale function for the Scene in which the control is drawn, the Bitmap getter retrieves the Scale for the current
>    device. If Scene is not defined, then the 1.0 value for Scale is
>    accepted.
> 2. If MultiResBitmap is assigned, then the getter gets the Bitmap from the bitmap item having the scale best matching to the obtained Scale
>    (not including empty bitmap items.)
> 3. If the getter does not find any not empty bitmap item, then the getter tries to retrieve an empty bitmap item having the scale exactly
>    matching to the obtained Scale.
> 4. If the getter cannot find an empty bitmap item having the obtained Scale, then the getter creates a new bitmap item with the obtained
>    Scale and returns the bitmap from the created bitmap item.
> 5. If the obtained Scale <= 0 or MultiResBitmap is not assigned, the exception is raised.

Comment: Thank you about this Embarcadero link, but I've of course see so many docs on the web but without any the beginning of solving...